# How to call event onChange in a input when i click a button and update de value of input React

Tags: reactjs

I trying to create a component with input type number, but i have a problem when my value change, the event onChange that input is not called, how i can fix this? because i have to pass the new value to the father component.
My code

```
//My Component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AddCircle, RemoveCircle } from '@material-ui/icons'

import './inputnumber.css'
function InputNumber({ defaultValue, onClick, value, onInputChange }) {
    const [Value, setVal] = useState(value|| 1)
    function updateValue(value){
        setVal(value)
        return onInputChange(value)
    }
    function  IncrementValue(){
        setVal(Value + 1)
     
    }
    function DecrementValue(){
        setVal(Value - 1)
    }
    return (
        <div className='inputNumber-Container'>
            <AddCircle onClick = {() => IncrementValue()}  className='input-number-button'></AddCircle>
            <input type='number' value = {Value} id = 'inputvalue'  onChange = {(e) => updateValue(e.target.value)} ></input>
            <RemoveCircle onClick = {() => DecrementValue()} className='input-number-button'></RemoveCircle>
        </div>
    )
}

export default InputNumber;
```

When i use the input and change the value manually its works, but when i try to use the buttons, my value update normaly but the event onChange don't pass to the father component the value updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both a local `Value` and a `value` from props. Your code right now doesn't work because you are not calling `onInputChange` to update the parent state from your `IncrementValue` and `DecrementValue` handlers.  You only call `onInputChange` from the `updateValue` handler on the `input` `onChange` event.

It is not a good idea to duplicate props in state because it leads to out-of-sync values like this.  You should remove the local value state and just rely on the parent's value. This is what we call a "controlled component" because it doesn't manage any state of its own.

Instead of calling `setVal` in your increment and decrement handlers you should call `onInputChange` to update the parent state.

```
function InputNumber({ defaultValue = 1, value, onInputChange }) {
  function updateValue(value) {
    onInputChange(value);
  }
  function IncrementValue() {
    onInputChange(value + 1);
  }
  function DecrementValue() {
    onInputChange(value - 1);
  }
  return (
    <div className="inputNumber-Container">
      <AddCircle
        onClick={() => IncrementValue()}
        className="input-number-button"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={value ?? defaultValue}
        id="inputvalue"
        onChange={(e) => updateValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <RemoveCircle
        onClick={() => DecrementValue()}
        className="input-number-button"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course those handlers are simple enough that you can just write them inline.

```
function InputNumber({ defaultValue = 1, value, onInputChange }) {
  return (
    <div className="inputNumber-Container">
      <AddCircle
        onClick={() => onInputChange(value + 1)}
        className="input-number-button"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={value ?? defaultValue}
        id="inputvalue"
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)}
      />
      <RemoveCircle
        onClick={() =>  onInputChange(value - 1)}
        className="input-number-button"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help, now my component is working.